# symlink to my php script, other website use the same script without copy

Tags: php, symlink

I have one script and many websites,
because they are on the same server how can I execute same script on all websites
and of course I need to know from witch website asked my script to know to give different results
with different templates....
I thought to place symlink and it should be fastest solution

Hier is example:
Script.php is on /home/website.com/ this is my main script
on /home/website1.com is other website and this I want to use script.php without copy same script to /home/website1.com.

And if I call from /home/website1.com script I need to script see that website1.com called it and give other results :)

Comment: you can't use a common location like: `/path/to/my/code` and use it in all your code?

Comment: -1 for poor description AND what is your actual problem? +(few typo, and bad formatting)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Apache, make sure you have the directive `FollowSymLinks true` set.

Also, you'll need to check the permissions on the link itself (must be able to execute), and the destination (must be able to read the destination).